# Can I route a VLAN on a Sonicwall to use a different gateway?

Tags: vlan, sonicwall

Here is my scenario. I have a Sonicwall with LAN 192.168.16.x with a VLAN(VOIP)of 10.10.20.X
The PBX has a 192.168.16.X IP

[image]

The ISP just installed a ESBC on the network and I gave it a 192.168.16.x IP. I was told that the PBX had to use the ESBC as its gateway, however by doing that the VLAN or IP phones are unable to see the PBX.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: Please provide a simple diagram of your network, and the model of you ESBC.

Comment: I assume I can attach something.

Comment: You can edit your question to include an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gateway for the PBX should be the firewall (192.168.16.1).  But you need to add a route (default) to the PBX to send SIP traffic to the SBC.

Comment: Thank you Ron. That is what it was originally. I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: I created a route from the PBX to the SBC for VOIP services and that seemed to solve the problem. Thanks Ron.